# Get videos in Android app using Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a high school project, I need to get a list of uploaded videos on a Facebook page inside my own Android app. 
Facebook SDK suggests the following code for this:

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
session,
"/{page-id}/videos/uploaded",
null,
HttpMethod.GET,
new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

I have inserted the ID of my page in the Request.

The problem is that I need to supply an Access token. Using the Graph Api Explorer I can browse the output of the query supplying my access token on their side. How do I supply the access token inside the Java code?

The response I am getting is this one:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 104,       errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An access token is required to request this resource.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Can you please help me out how to supply the access token to the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AccesToken is obtained through Facebook Login Service, when a user is logged in, Facebook generates one. You should take a look at

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

It is a library that simplifies common Facebook API tasks (such as login user).